# Could a strong AC electric field adversely affect the capacity of a lithium battery?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrochemistry

I run some battery powered test equipment in close proximity (~10cm) to a conductor carrying 25kV (50Hz AC). I find the battery life is much shorter than expected, having checked the current consumption of the equipment. Could the electric field adversely affect battery operation? The battery is a primary lithium thionyl chloride 3.6V D-cell, rated at 17Ah.

Comment: I kinda doubt it. Are you sure that it's actually decreasing the capacity? Have you measured the current draw as a function of time to make sure that it's not just the equipment drawing more or less power at certain times?

Comment: Yes; current draw was verified to be as expected.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. How much was the change in life? 10 percent? 50 percent?

Comment: Around 30% of what we expected!

Comment: That's quite a big loss of power. What is the battery life normally? If you just place a battery next to the conductor and leave it there, does it go dead even though it's not connected to anything? If you post on ElectricalEngineeringSE you might also get some useful responses, as I actually have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: We use a bank of 16 in parallel, all with protective diodes. Expected life is around 3 months (at least). We are not able to easily perform your suggested check, as the kit is mounted on a train to which access is limited. Thanks for your thoughts.